# Table columns not equal

Tags: css, html-table

I have the following table. I use `colspan="4"` for 2 td - but they are not equal. First column is greater than second. What is this due to?

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">         
            <tr><td colspan="8" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="8" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr>
                <td style="position: relative; font-size: 14px;" colspan="8">
               text
                </td>
   </tr>
  
   <tr><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    To:
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    From:
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                   text<br>
                   text<br>
                   text<br>
                   text
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">
                   text<br>
                   text<br>
                   text<br>
                   text
                </td>
            </tr>
  //in the same way other rows
  </table>
```

It looks in this way: 
[image]

Comment: They are the same verify this by inspecting element, of may be I am wrong

Comment: No, when I inspect elements, first column is 868px, second is 634px.

Comment: then in that case code , show by you is not sufficient , add more code in this , or a  secreenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you meant, but I've given it a shot. I added a `colgroup` to depict the difference more clearly, and replaced the HTML5 deprecated `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` attributes.

```css
table {
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100px;  /*Needs to be greater than the size of 'From:'*/
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="4" style="background-color:red">
    <col span="4" style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; font-size: 14px;" colspan="8">
      text
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      To:
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      From:
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      text
      <br>text
      <br>text
      <br>text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Although looking at your image, the following structure would be more appropriate:

```css
table {
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /*Needs to be greater than the size of 'From:'*/
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
caption {
  color: #002B7F;
  font-weight: bold;
}
caption,
th {
  text-align: left;
}
thead {
  background-color: #007C66;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>text</caption>
  <thead>
    <th>To:</th>
    <th>From:</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! They are equal now. ` table-layout: fixed;` this did the trick.